# Calculate commission - Rates decrease when turnover increase

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

It's been a long time since I attended a mathematics class. Once I was able to solve this myself, but apparently not anymore:

A company gets a commission from sales. The commission is 
10% on turnover <= 1 million, 
8% on turnover > 1 million to <= 3 millions, and
6% on turnover > 3 millions

I need an equation where the actual turnover is known, and the equation gives the earned commission.

I.'ve made a couple of attempts on equations with 3 unknowns, but I have no idea where to start.

Help very appreciated!

Best regards,
Anders

Comment: What's the problem? You already provided the function yourself. You only need to convert the percentages to a fraction of the turnover amount.

Comment: By the way, I don't see a system of equations here. There are only two variables (commission and turnover) and they are directly linked with an equation that you already provided.

Comment: Please don't downvote my question just because it is (in your opinion) simple. Let me give you an example to illustrate why this is challenging for a math noob: If the turnover is 4 million, then the commision will not be 4 mill x 6%. Instead it will be (1 mill x 10%) + (2 mill x 8%) + (1 mill x 6%). As long as the turnover always is higher than 3 mill, it will be an easy equation, one would just have to subtract the already calculated turnover from each "subtotal". But what if the turnover is only 500 000? The 6% and 8%-rates would have to be ignored to avoid negative "subtotals".

Comment: Ah alright, well this aspect was not indicated in your original question. But reading your comment, it seems like you are very well equipped to answer this question. I mean the part where you calculated the answer for turnover = 4 million. Now you just have to generalize it.

Comment: Congrats on getting at least $101$ reputation by the way :)

Comment: This is exactly how the federal, United States, graduated income tax works. If you search for _graduated tax_ you'll find many lucid explanations, and some tools. As @DavidK 's answer shows, there is no single "formula" for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way of writing your function in a standard mathematical notation,
where $c(t)$ represents the total amount of the commission earned for a turnover of $t$:

$$
c(t) = \begin{cases}
 0.1 t & t \leq 1\,000\,000 \\
100\,000 + 0.08(t - 1\,000\,000) & 1\,000\,000 < t \leq 3\,000\,000 \\
260\,000 + 0.06(t - 3\,000\,000) & t > 3\,000\,000 \\
\end{cases}
$$

I chose that form because it is close to the way the rules are expressed in the problem statement. For example, when the turnover is more than three million, the formula shows that the total commission is the amount earned on the portion of the turnover that is below three million, which is
$0.1\times 1\,000\,000 + 0.08\times 2\,000\,000 = 260\,000,$
plus $6\%$ of the portion of the turnover that is above three million.

A slightly different way to write the same function is
$$
c(t) = \begin{cases}
 0.1 t & t \leq 1\,000\,000 \\
20\,000 + 0.08 t & 1\,000\,000 < t \leq 3\,000\,000 \\
80\,000 + 0.06 t & t > 3\,000\,000 \\
\end{cases}
$$

using facts such as 
$$260\,000 + 0.06(t - 3\,000\,000)
= 260\,000 + 0.06 t - 180\,000 = 80\,000 + 0.06 t.$$